# PHP Tidy removes valid tags

Tags: php, html, tidy

I'm using php extension tidy-html to clean up php output. I know that tidy removes invalid tags and can't even handle HTML5 doctype, but I'm using tag `<menu>` which used to be in HTML specifications. However, it gets changed for `<ul>` anyway.

Oddly enough, It didn't do so *before*. I changed the tidy config and it has break. Now I've turned off all options that messes with tags, but it didn't help.

My script is quite verbose:

```
$tidy_config = array(
    'char-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'output-html' => true,
    'numeric-entities' => false,
    'ascii-chars' => false,
    'doctype' => 'loose',
    'clean' => false,
    'bare' => false,
    'fix-uri' => true,
    'indent' => true,
    'indent-spaces' => 2,
    'tab-size' => 2,
    'wrap-attributes' => true,
    'wrap' => 0,
    'indent-attributes' => true,
    'join-classes' => false,
    'join-styles' => false,
    'fix-bad-comments' => true,
    'fix-backslash' => true,
    'replace-color' => false,
    'wrap-asp' => false,
    'wrap-jste' => false,
    'wrap-php' => false,
    'wrap-sections' => false,
    'drop-proprietary-attributes' => false,
    'hide-comments' => false,
    'hide-endtags' => false,
    'drop-empty-paras' => true,
    'quote-ampersand' => true,
    'quote-marks' => true,
    'quote-nbsp' => true,
    'vertical-space' => true,
    'wrap-script-literals' => false,
    'tidy-mark' => true,
    'merge-divs' => false,
    'repeated-attributes' => 'keep-last',
    'break-before-br' => false
);

$tidy_config2 = array(
    'tidy-mark' => false,
    'vertical-space' => false,
    'hide-comments' => true,
    'indent-spaces' => 0,
    'tab-size' => 1,
    'wrap-attributes' => false,
    'numeric-entities' => true,
    'ascii-chars' => true,
    'hide-endtags' => true,
    'indent' => false
);
$tidy_config = array_merge($tidy_config, $tidy_config2);

$dtm = preg_match(self::doctypeMatch, $output, $dt);
$output = tidy_repair_string($output, $tidy_config, 'utf8');

// tidy screws up doctype --fixed
if($dtm)
    $output = preg_replace(self::doctypeMatch, $dt[0], $output);

$output = preg_replace('!>[\n\r]+<!', '><', $output);

unset($tidy_config);

return $output;
```

Note that it is more complicated than this (hence the two arrays). I've just cut off unnecessary code.

Comment: Do you have a backup you can restore from? When you get this fixed, think about storing your tidy config under version control. Even RCS would save you here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### DISCLAIMER:

I don't think my answer is very... neat. It's more of a hakish way to use HTMLTidy with HTML5 (which currently it does not support). To accomplish that **I use regex to parse HTML**, which, according to most, is the the root of all evil or the [cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). If someone knows a better way, please enlighten us, since I don't feel very secure in using regex to parse html. I've tested it with many examples but I'm quite sure it's not bullet proof.

### Intro

The menu tag was deprecated in HTML4 and XHTML1, being replaced by ul (unordered list). It was, however, [redefined in HTML5 and hence is a valid tag according to HTML5 specifications.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/menu.html#menu) SinceHTMLTidy does not support HTML5 and uses XHTML or HTML specifications, as the OP pointed, it replaces the then deprecated tag menu to ul (or adds the ul tag), even when you specifically tell it not to.

### My suggestion

This function replaces the menu tag with a custom tag prior to parsing it with tidy. It then replaces the custom tag with menu again.

```
function tidyHTML5($buffer)
{
    $buffer = str_replace('<menu', '<mytag', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace('menu>', 'mytag>', $buffer);
    $tidy = new tidy();
    $options = array(
            'hide-comments'         => true,
            'tidy-mark'             => false,
            'indent'                => true,
            'indent-spaces'         => 4,
            'new-blocklevel-tags'   => 'menu,mytag,article,header,footer,section,nav',
            'new-inline-tags'       => 'video,audio,canvas,ruby,rt,rp',
            'doctype'               => '<!DOCTYPE HTML>',
            //'sort-attributes'     => 'alpha',
            'vertical-space'        => false,
            'output-xhtml'          => true,
            'wrap'                  => 180,
            'wrap-attributes'       => false,
            'break-before-br'       => false,
            'char-encoding'         => 'utf8',
            'input-encoding'        => 'utf8',
            'output-encoding'       => 'utf8'
    );

    $tidy->parseString($buffer, $options, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();

    $html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>' . PHP_EOL . $tidy->html();
    $html = str_replace('<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">', '<html>', $html);
    $html = str_replace('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">', '<html>', $html);

    //Hackish stuff starts here
    //We use regex to parse html, which is usually a bad idea
    //But currently there is no alternative to it, since tidy is not MENU TAG friendly
    preg_match_all('/\<mytag(?:[^\>]*)\>\s*\<ul>/', $html, $matches);
    foreach($matches as $m) {
        $mo = $m;
        $m = str_replace('mytag', 'menu', $m);
        $m = str_replace('<ul>', '', $m);
        $html = str_replace($mo, $m, $html);
    }
    $html = str_replace('<mytag', '<menu', $html);
    $html = str_replace('</ul></mytag>', '</menu>', $html);
    $html = str_replace('mytag>', 'menu>', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

**TEST:**

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo tidyHTML5('<menu><li>Lorem ipsum</li></menu><div></div><menu   ><a href="#">lala</a><form id="jj"><button>btn</button></form></menu><menu style="color: white" id="nhecos"><li>blabla</li><li>sdfsdfsdf</li></menu>');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <menu>

            <li>Lorem ipsum
            </li>
        </menu><menu style="color: white" id="nhecos">

            <li>blabla
            </li>
            <li>sdfsdfsdf
            </li>
        </menu>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried it all but it didn't worke. I thought that it might be caused by an archaic tidy version, so I downloaded newer php with newer extension, but it didn't help. It seems that tidy completly ignores the new-*-tags config directives. If I have <li> inside the menu, it's turned into an unordered list. If I have just some random text inside, it turns into a div (not depending on the config). I'm  slowly becoming desperate. I guess I just might have to stop using tidy :/

Comment: that's strange, since I use tidy in my HTML5 pages and works great! Check my edited post, I've posted the complete function I use to parse HTML5

Comment: I've just tried that. See [this image](http://i.imgur.com/2ZIE0) :/

Also please note that I'm trying to use HTML (there is no XHTML parser in older IE). I guess that you send mime type text/html anyway.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Check my edited answer, I've tested it's and it works, although it kind of hackish

Comment: It's right now. I've actually thought that the problem is with every unknown tag, but it appears to happen only with the menu tag. This is probably a bug. Thanks for your patience solving this :)

Comment: +1, pretty decent answer, check mine for some improvements. Also, I've found that setting the `doctype` to `omit` and then prefixing it is more reliable than setting it to the HTML5 one. One more thing, why `output-xhtml` and not `output-html`?

Comment: Oh, I just read the rest of your code... Why aren't you just doing `$buffer = str_replace(array('<menu', '</menu'), array('<temp', '</temp'), $buffer);` before tidying and then `$buffer = str_replace(array('<temp', '</temp'), array('<menu', '</menu'), $buffer);` after? I don't get the need for `preg_match_all` and all the `ul` replacements.

Comment: @AlixAxel html does not support (by definition) xml tags (that is, tags with "custom" names)

ALl that redudanct code you refer is to catch all possible combinations, so that mytag gets replaced with menu. For instance,
 "<   menu   >" is valid HTML and won't get replaced with your code. Also, you can namespace menu "<namespace:menu>".

Comment: @Tivie: Oh yeah, you're right. But if the purpose is to clean up PHP output (and it doesn't make sense to use Tidy for anything else when HTML5 is involved, like purifying) it's unlikely that the developer will "trick" the `tidyHTML5` function with stuff like `< mEnU   >` instead of a simple `<menu>`, and even if he does that unintentionally he will probably spot it and fix it. Usually, you want the HTML to be served as quickly as possible and your approach adds a lot of overhead (I would guess ~300% compared to mine, but I can benchmark). Anyway, good work with the general approach.

Comment: @AlixAxel humm... Actually, I don't think there is much point in "tydying" your own html. I usually use tidy when consuming a public HTML source from somewhere in the interwebs so that I can parse it more easily.

Comment: @Tivie: Me too, but apparently that's what the OP is doing and sometimes I also don't like to expose my partials (they get un-indented) and removing all whitespace via `preg_replace` messes up the pre-like tags.

Comment: This looks absolutely disgusting! I'd be far too scared to use this!

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the old Tidy from stripping away empty tags such as `<span class="icon ..."></span>`? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `<a href=""><div>asas</div></a>` ? gives `<a href=""></a><div>asas</div>`

Answer (score 8):

According to [W3C tidy-html5 fork](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/blob/master/src/tags.c), the correct configuration for new tags should be:

```
'new-blocklevel-tags' => 'article aside audio bdi canvas details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup main menu menuitem nav section source summary template track video',
'new-empty-tags' => 'command embed keygen source track wbr',
'new-inline-tags' => 'audio command datalist embed keygen mark menuitem meter output progress source time video wbr',
```

You'll notice that `new-blocklevel-tags` has a weird `temp` tag defined, that's supposed to be the replacement for the *old obsolete* `menu` tag, as @tivie mentioned in his answer you have to replace it.

Also, the tags `audio` and `video` appear in both `new-blocklevel-tags` and `new-inline-tags`, and that changes the way tidy will output the HTML, as it is:

```
<video src="movie.webm">
<track kind="subtitles" label="English" src="subtitles.vtt" srclang="en"></video>
```

If you drop `video` from the `new-inline-tags`:

```
<video src="movie.webm">
  <track kind="subtitles" label="English" src="subtitles.vtt" srclang="en">
</video>
```

Dropping `video` from `new-blocklevel-tags` yields:

```
<video src="movie.webm">
<track kind="subtitles" label="English" src="subtitles.vtt" srclang="en"></video>
```

Personally, I prefer `audio` and `video` to behave like block level tags, but that's up to you.

Additionally, the `tags.c` also defines `command` as being `CM_HEAD` and `embed` as `CM_IMG`. Unfortunately, I have no idea what these stand for and I don't think it's possible to emulate them.

One other thing: if you don't define `new-empty-tags`, you'll get weird outputs:

```
<video src="movie.webm">
  <track kind="subtitles" label="English" src="subtitles.vtt" srclang="en">
  </track>
</video>
```

---

### Addendum

If you also want to support the [WHATWG recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements), you should add the tags:

- [`data`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element) as a inline element
- [`dialog`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#the-dialog-element) as a [block level](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_dialog_tag.cfm) element (?)

---

Here's my complete approach:

```
function Tidy5($string, $options = null, $encoding = 'utf8')
{
   if (extension_loaded('tidy') === true)
   {
      $default = array
      (
         'anchor-as-name' => false,
         'break-before-br' => true,
         'char-encoding' => $encoding,
         'decorate-inferred-ul' => false,
         'doctype' => 'omit',
         'drop-empty-paras' => false,
         'drop-font-tags' => true,
         'drop-proprietary-attributes' => false,
         'force-output' => false,
         'hide-comments' => false,
         'indent' => true,
         'indent-attributes' => false,
         'indent-spaces' => 2,
         'input-encoding' => $encoding,
         'join-styles' => false,
         'logical-emphasis' => false,
         'merge-divs' => false,
         'merge-spans' => false,
         'new-blocklevel-tags' => 'article aside audio bdi canvas details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup main menu menuitem nav section source summary template track video',
         'new-empty-tags' => 'command embed keygen source track wbr',
         'new-inline-tags' => 'audio command datalist embed keygen mark menuitem meter output progress source time video wbr',
         'newline' => 0,
         'numeric-entities' => false,
         'output-bom' => false,
         'output-encoding' => $encoding,
         'output-html' => true,
         'preserve-entities' => true,
         'quiet' => true,
         'quote-ampersand' => true,
         'quote-marks' => false,
         'repeated-attributes' => 1,
         'show-body-only' => true,
         'show-warnings' => false,
         'sort-attributes' => 1,
         'tab-size' => 4,
         'tidy-mark' => false,
         'vertical-space' => true,
         'wrap' => 0,
      );

      $doctype = $menu = null;

      if ((strncasecmp($string, '<!DOCTYPE', 9) === 0) || (strncasecmp($string, '<html', 5) === 0))
      {
         $doctype = '<!DOCTYPE html>'; $options['show-body-only'] = false;
      }

      $options = (is_array($options) === true) ? array_merge($default, $options) : $default;

      if (strpos($string, '<menu') !== false)
      {
         $menu = array
         (
            '<menu' => '<menutidy',
            '</menu' => '</menutidy',
         );
      }

      if (isset($menu) === true)
      {
         $string = str_replace(array_keys($menu), $menu, $string);
      }

      $string = tidy_repair_string($string, $options, $encoding);

      if (empty($string) !== true)
      {
         if (isset($menu) === true)
         {
            $string = str_replace($menu, array_keys($menu), $string);
         }

         if (isset($doctype) === true)
         {
            $string = $doctype . "\n" . $string;
         }

         return $string;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 Is this tidy fork ready for production? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Tivie: No, I haven't. But I've seen it being recommended here on StackOverflow time and time again.

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the old Tidy from stripping away empty tags such as `<span class="icon ..."></span>`? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `<a href=""><div>asas</div></a>` ? gives `<a href=""></a><div>asas</div> `